# Angular 2 / HTML interface to a Netty server

Tags: java, angular, netty, asyncsocket, json-rpc

I've developed an async server in Java using the Netty framework. It listens on both HTTP and TCP socket connections on the same port. The server API is accessible via JSON-RPC (essentially, clients and the server exchange JSON-RPC messages). I developed async clients both in Java and in Python and everything works great.

Now, I'm trying to develop a browser interface to the server so that I could invoke the JSON-RPC methods directly from the browser. I would like to use Angular 2 to build the UI. How should I approach this problem? I see there is socket.io, would it be a good choice? Can it work with an arbitrary server?

Any help greatly appreciated!